# Asp Web Api Controller Best Practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 controllers. Categories (api/product-categories) and Products (api/products). My question is that if i have a route that get all products that belong to certain category (api/product-categories/1/products), where should i put this method? is it in product or category controller?

Comment: products controller and filter is your category.

Comment: See you need to understand that Web API is essentially a resource based arrangement (in an ideal world and as per best practices). So if the resource you are trying to fetch is **Product** then by convention that operation should be handled by the **ProductController** and then any further filtering, sorting, paging etc. be applied to the result set in your [HttpGet] for products